# how to reject droppable element in container with the help of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

My `jsfiddle` is http://jsfiddle.net/aNreg/44/

Now I can drag and drop some elements, but I want to reject one element from container.

Comment: Why have you tagged this as having php?

Comment: [Please make your question self-contained and include the relevant parts of the code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114942/when-jsfiddle-and-other-related-sites-are-gone-so-is-the-information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check updated code:

http://jsfiddle.net/aNreg/111/

Your divs had the same id `shoppingCart1` and `droppable` function can be added to selector `.shoppingCart ol` instead of each id.

Comment: No bro this is working... but not as per my requirement. i want to the numbers like 400 200 300 500 700 from this number one number should be dragable but not dropable, understand?